# Issues in changing font size in vim

Tags: vimrc

I use konsole terminal emulator and I am facing an issue with changing the font size in vim.

If I add the following snippet into my `.vimrc`. In the vim application, the font size will snap back to the original value as seen in the gif. Note that in the video, `Ctrl =` binding is used to increase the font size of my terminal.

```
" Change cursor in the various different mode
let &t_SI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=1\x7"
let &t_SR = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=2\x7"
let &t_EI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=0\x7"
if exists('$TMUX')
  let &t_SI = "\ePtmux;\e" . &t_SI . "\e\\"
  let &t_EI = "\ePtmux;\e" . &t_EI . "\e\\"
endif
```

[image: Don't work]
However, once I remove the following snippet it works as intended.
[image]

Comment: hmmm, managed to get it to work when i change the font size manually through the GUI, but not when I use `Ctrl =` binding.

Comment: It's *possible* that the issue is unrelated to Vim. Have you tried sending the same escape codes outside of Vim? In bash, I think this should send the sequence you've bound to `t_SI`: `echo -e '\e]50;CursorShape=1\x07'`

Comment: Hey @Rich, thanks for helping:) yup the escape code works. In my zsh, when i echo the sequence, nothing is being shown. I've taken that snippet from https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Change_cursor_shape_in_different_modes#For%20Konsole%20in%20KDE4

Answer (score 2):

I also have this problem. Unfortunately, I think the fault lies with Konsole.

When I open Konsole, I can click `Settings-> Edit Current Profile` and it correctly edits my profile. Then I send the cursor change sequence (echo to the terminal, or from vim). If the font size has been changed, it will reset as described in the question. I then again go to `Settings-> Edit Current Profile`, and now the profile name is empty, and there is a warning stating that it is empty.

I suspect Konsole implements the cursor change command by making an adjustment to the current profile, and fails to consider any changes you have made since originally loading that profile.

If I were running a new version of Konsole, I would be inclined to file a bug report, but I'm rather out of date. So, my answer is to update your version and file a bug report if it still happens.

While this answer isn't terribly helpful to solve the problem, I think it may at least help with diagnosis.